# SELECT COUNT with JOIN optimization for tables with > 100M rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have following query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a0_.created_date FROM 1 FOR 10) AS sclr_0, 
       COUNT(1) AS sclr_1 
FROM applications a0_ INNER JOIN 
     package_codes p1_ ON a0_.id = p1_.application_id 
WHERE a0_.created_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' AND
      p1_.type = 'Package 1'
GROUP BY sclr_0
```

--- EDIT ---

Most of you have focused on GROUP BY and SUBSTRING, but this is not the root of problem.

Following query have the same execution time:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS sclr_1 
FROM applications a0_ INNER JOIN 
     package_codes p1_ ON a0_.id = p1_.application_id 
WHERE a0_.created_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' AND
      p1_.type = 'Package 1'
```

--- EDIT 2 ---

After adding index on applications.created_date and forcing the query to use specified indexes as @DDS suggests the execution time drops to ~750ms

The current query looks like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a0_.created_date FROM 1 FOR 10) AS sclr_0, 
       COUNT(1) AS sclr_1 
FROM applications a0_ USE INDEX (applications_created_date_idx) INNER JOIN 
     package_codes p1_ USE INDEX (PRIMARY, UNIQ_70A9C6AA3E030ACD, package_codes_type_idx) ON a0_.id = p1_.application_id 
WHERE a0_.created_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' AND
      p1_.type = 'Package 1'
GROUP BY sclr_0
```

--- EDIT 3 ---

I have found that using to much indexes in query may cause that in some cases MySQL will use non optimal indexes, so the final query should looks as following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a0_.created_date FROM 1 FOR 10) AS sclr_0, 
       COUNT(1) AS sclr_1 
FROM applications a0_ USE INDEX (applications_created_date_idx) INNER JOIN 
     package_codes p1_ USE INDEX (package_codes_application_idx) ON a0_.id = p1_.application_id 
WHERE a0_.created_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' AND
      p1_.type = 'Package 1'
GROUP BY sclr_0
```

--- END EDIT ---

package_codes contains over 100.000.000 records.

applications contains over 250.000 records.

The query takes 2 minutes to get result. Is there any way to optimize it?
I'm stuck on MySQL 5.5.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `applications`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `applications_created_date_idx` (`created_date`);

ALTER TABLE `applications`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `package_codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `application_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `disabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_data` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `package_codes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_70A9C6AA3E030ACD` (`application_id`),
  ADD KEY `package_codes_code_idx` (`code`),
  ADD KEY `package_codes_type_idx` (`type`),
  ADD KEY `package_codes_application_idx` (`application_id`),
  ADD KEY `package_codes_code_application_idx` (`code`,`application_id`);

ALTER TABLE `package_codes`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `package_codes`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_70A9C6AA3E030ACD` FOREIGN KEY (`application_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`);
```

Comment: Why do you think that 2 minutes is long time? What is your hardware? Maybe you are running on  limits of your disk subsystem? Have you concidered to calculate aggregates periodically?

Comment: @AlexYu this query is used to generate live overall statistics, and it should not take more than few seconds to be acceptable in production by our customer. The machine is IMO strong enough for this kind of thing (4x E7-4860 - 40 cores, 80 threads, 256GB RAM, hardware RAID 1 on SSDs with enabled controller cache)

Comment: Try to improve your indexes. But if you still face such issues, you may eto go for columnstore (at least for this kind of 'live' queries). Also I suggest you to add a new 'column' with the 'substr' result, so you don't have to calculate it all the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding index on applications.created_date and forcing the query to use specified indexes as @DDS suggests the execution time drops to ~750ms

The final query should look as following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a0_.created_date FROM 1 FOR 10) AS sclr_0, 
       COUNT(1) AS sclr_1 
FROM applications a0_ USE INDEX (applications_created_date_idx) INNER JOIN 
     package_codes p1_ USE INDEX (package_codes_application_idx) ON a0_.id = p1_.application_id 
WHERE a0_.created_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' AND
      p1_.type = 'Package 1'
GROUP BY sclr_0
```

Comment: Does it mean that you found solution? It's perfectly fine to: a) answer your own question, b) chose your own answer as solution

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to avoid this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a0_.created_date FROM 1 FOR 10) AS sclr_0, 
[...]  
GROUP BY sclr_0
```

because each time the dbms 'recalculates' the field and can't use indexes on it, if you put this data in it's own column and make an index on it your performance should improve

Or, at least, use date_part function, so mysql could manage to use its indexing (obviously you should add an index on application.created_date)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a0_.created_date FROM 1 FOR 10) AS sclr_0, COUNT(1) AS sclr_1 
FROM applications a0_ INNER JOIN 
     package_codes p1_ ON (a0_.id = p1_.application_id and a0_.created_date 
BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' and p1_.type = 'Package 1')      
FORCE INDEX (date_index, type_index)
Group by date(a0_.created_date)
```

another optimization is to 'push' the conditions to the 'on' clause so mysql 'filters' the data before joining -> join is performed across far less rows

EDIT:
this is to create an index on the date

```
CREATE INDEX date_index ON application(created_date);
```

If you have much more types than dates you should consider putting the index on type.

```
CREATE INDEX type_index ON package_codes(type);
```

[EDIT 2]
please post the result of

```
select count(distinct date(a0_.created_date)) as N_DATES, count(distinct type)as N_TYPES
FROM applications a0_ INNER JOIN 
     package_codes p1_ ON a0_.id = p1_.application_id
```

Just to have an idea on witch index will be more selective

Useful [link](https://blog.nodeswat.com/making-slow-queries-fast-with-composite-indexes-in-mysql-eb452a8d6e46) for index optimization using MySQL

Comment: After changing the query to:

SELECT a0_.created_date AS sclr_0, 
       COUNT(1) AS sclr_1 
FROM applications a0_ INNER JOIN 
     package_codes p1_ ON a0_.id = p1_.application_id 
WHERE a0_.created_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' AND
      p1_.type = 'Package 1'
GROUP BY year(a0_.created_date), month(a0_.created_date), day(a0_.created_date)

the execution time is still 2 minutes

Comment: Do you have an index on application.created_date? Also try to push the filtering conditions inside the join (post was edited)

Comment: Please check updated issue description. The problem is somewhere else. Simplified query has the same execution time.

Comment: added syntax to add the index you need

Comment: No changes in execution time after adding index on application.created_date. I have updated the database create queries.

Comment: Have you tryied forcing the index use? (use index) as in my edited answer? Another thing you should post is the execution plan (I have no idea about how print them from mysql).

Comment: After your suggestions the query is now executing ~750ms. Thanks! Do you see any more places to optimization? See EDIT 2 in issue description.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you added second index (on type)? if no, add it. As suggested by cherrysoft, you can try to add another (composite) index on `created_date,application_id` as suggested by @cherrysoft

Comment: Type had index on first version so I don't had to add it. I found one strange behavior in the solution developed with your help. When I execute query with p1_.type = 'Pack01 Test1 Mini' the execution time is ~900ms, (there are about 10k records matching to this condition), but when I execute query p1_.type = 'Pack01 Test1 Mini Max' the execution time is 30 seconds (there are about 20 matching records). Do you have idea why the query with longer type value and less elements in applications table is executing longer?

Comment: Index lacks selectivity? Use `EXPLAIN` before your query to have the execution plan and see where is your resource hog

Comment: @DDS (and cherrysoft) -- `INDEX(created_date, application_id)` won't work since the columns are not in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a composite index.  It appears that you have created individual indexes on the table.  In this instance you want a separate index on created_date in package_codes and also a composite index for created_date and type.

Maybe cast the date prior and group by after.

Comment: "a composite index for created_date and type." - created_date is from table applications, type is from table package_codes. Do MySQL allows to create composite indexes between two tables?

Comment: Apologies, I was looking at the middle query (in the posts current edited form) and didn't see the applications table.  It looks like there have been a few edits.  No, MySQL doesn't allow composite index across two tables - not sure of any RDBMS that does.

Comment: @cherrysoft - There once was a 3rd party Engine that could make composite indexes across tables.  Under the covers, it would actually combine table to make that possible.  (It is no more.)

Comment: That's pretty interesting Rick, combining the tables is actually an innovative approach to achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal indexes are

```
p1_:  (type, application_id)
a0_:  (created_date, id)
```

These apply to all(?) versions of the query presented except those "forcing" an index.

The Optimizer will attempt to decide whether to start with `p1_` or `a0_`.  And, with those indexes, it should have a good shot at picking the better table.

`SUBSTRING(a0_.created_date FROM 1 FOR 10)` can be simplified to `DATE(a0_.created_date)`, but I doubt if it will change the performance.

Note that the indexes will be "covering", thereby giving an extra boost.  `EXPLAIN` indicates such by saying `Using index` (not `Using index condition`).

A further improvement:  Get rid of `package_codes.id` and promote `application_id` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This might lead to a simplification of the query!

My advice applies to (perhaps) all versions of MySQL.